# Encoding in PDF file using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, font-encodings

My code are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{unicode-math}%

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Path = ../Fonts/TimesLTStd/ ,
UprightFont= TimesLTStd-Roman.otf ,
BoldFont=TimesLTStd-Bold.otf ,
ItalicFont=TimesLTStd-Italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=TimesLTStd-BoldItalic.otf
]
{TimesLTStd-Roman}

\begin{document}

This is for test
\end{document}
```

And the output generated nicely, but in PDF font Encoding is shown as below:

[image]

But if I use either `LaTeX, dvips, ps2pdf` or `PDFLaTeX` font encoding is shown below:

[image]

My requirement is `XeLaTeX` PDF font encoding should be same as `LaTeX` or `PDFLaTeX` created output. Please suggest..

Comment: pdflatex uses fonts with at most 256 characters xelatex uses fonts with several thousand characters, how can you have a requirement to use the same encoding????

Comment: unrelated but you shouldn't use `xltxtra` and probably not `xunicode` with current xelatex

Comment: Why does this kind of encoding matters?